# How to render value by column from dynamic string mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Below sample data table below has the `SKU` column `-` separated dynamic string. This string contains the join table `alias` and `column names`. I am trying to get the values of those columns. Please, if anyone can help me, I will be greatly appreciated.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT d.device_type_name,a.serial, d.sku
FROM anticipated_device a 
JOIN inventory_device_attribute i on a.serial = i.serial
LEFT JOIN sku_by_device d on a.device_type_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN color c on i.color_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN grade g on i.verified_condition_id = g.id
LEFT JOIN phone_model pm on i.phone_model = pm.model
LEFT JOIN carrier_lock cl on i.carrier_lock_id = cl.id
LEFT JOIN computer_model cm on i.computer_model = cm.model
LEFT JOIN computer_year cy on i.computer_year = cy.year
LEFT JOIN screen_size ss on i.screen_size = ss.size
LEFT JOIN ghz gh on i.ghz = gh.ghz 
LEFT JOIN processor pr on i.processor = pr.processor
LEFT JOIN ram ra on i.ram = ra.ram 
LEFT JOIN storage st on i.storage_size = st.storage and i.storage_type=st.storage_type
LEFT JOIN tablet_model tm on i.tablet_gen = tm.model
LEFT JOIN tablet_connectivity tc on i.tablet_connectivity = tc.connectivity
LEFT JOIN band_color bc on i.band_color = bc.color
LEFT JOIN manufacturer mn on a.manufacturer_id = mn.id
LEFT JOIN watch_series ws on i.watch_series = ws.series
LEFT JOIN watch_size wsi on i.watch_size = wsi.size
LEFT JOIN model m on i.non_device_model_id = m.id;
```

**Sample data as below:**

```
|device_type_name |serial  |sku
|-----------------|--------|---------------------------------------------------------
|Computer Keyboard|A1314   |mn.sku_mapping-m.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping
|Phone            |a22ebe5f|pm.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping-cl.sku_mapping
|Phone            |A58642EF|pm.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping-cl.sku_mapping
|Phone            |ad9531f2|pm.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping-cl.sku_mapping
|Phone            |ad977028|pm.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping-cl.sku_mapping
|Phone            |afeeb4df|pm.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping-cl.sku_mapping
|Laptop           |A1315   |cm.sku_mapping-cy.sku_mapping-ss.sku_mapping-gh.sku_mapping-pr.sku_mapping-ra.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping
|Laptop           |a22ebe5f|cm.sku_mapping-cy.sku_mapping-ss.sku_mapping-gh.sku_mapping-pr.sku_mapping-ra.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping
|Laptop           |A58642EF|cm.sku_mapping-cy.sku_mapping-ss.sku_mapping-gh.sku_mapping-pr.sku_mapping-ra.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping
|Laptop           |ad9531f3|cm.sku_mapping-cy.sku_mapping-ss.sku_mapping-gh.sku_mapping-pr.sku_mapping-ra.sku_mapping-st.sku_mapping-c.sku_mapping
```

**Desired output**
I want output for `sku` column like below:

```
phone   - 546412 - Iphone-XS-512GB-Gry-UNL
Lapptop - 545646 - McbA-E15-13-1.6-i5-8-128S-Slv
```

Comment: Provide desired final output for shown sample data.

Comment: You select from only 2 tables, so you'd use only 2 tables as datasource and 3rd table in WHERE EXISTS. What is the reason to jooin so manu unneeded tables?

Comment: I just added desired output. I joined many tables because `alias.sku_mapping ` value comes from that `alias` tables.

Comment: *I just added desired output* I cannot understand how does these 2 output rows are obtained from shown 10 source rows..

Comment: 2 rows are just samples. It would be 10 rows for each.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)